# category and url without https redirect to homepage in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ssl, redirect, https

we have enabled https in our website and enabled 301 in admin section.
But the issue is with the category or product urls

example: i have https://www.boxdoccia.it/box-doccia/box-doccia-angolari/ , when change to http://www.boxdoccia.it/box-doccia/box-doccia-angolari/ return to homepage

Magento 1.7.0.2
-multiple store (ssl only for boxdoccia.it)

-Auto-redirect to Base URL -> yes 301

-secure and unsecure url -> https://www.boxdoccia.it

this is htaccess:

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################

## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################

## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks 

    RewriteEngine on

############################################


## workaround for HTTP authorization

## in CGI environment


    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


############################################

## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]

    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=302]

############################################

## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################

## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


############################################

## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

############################################

## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides

## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off

    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    FileETag none

#####

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)boxdoccia.it
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:boxdoccia_it]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)boxdoccia.it
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)allandmore.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:allandmore_com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)allandmore.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)piattodoccia.it
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:piattodoccia_it]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)piattodoccia.it
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this after 
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: and in google webmaster we add http:// and https:// site with 2 different sitemap?

Comment: for google webmaster i suggest please check this url.
[link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/_TUXY8emefI)